# How to prevent keyboard and bottom textfield input blocking the ListView

Tags: flutter, listview

When keyboard is opened, the bottom TextField is pushed up and blocking the content of the ListView (See the video)
[image]

How can I prevent this behavior?

This is the code I used:

```
body: Column(children: [
  Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemCount: messages.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return MessageBubble(
          message: messages[index]['message'],
          isCurrentUser: messages[index]['type'] == 'user',
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
  // Chat message input bottom bar
  Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _messageController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Write message...",
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 15),
        FloatingActionButton.small(
          onPressed: onMessageSent,
          child: const Icon(Icons.send),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
]),
```

Your help would be much appreciated

Comment: padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),    wrap your listview with padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemCount: messages.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      reverse: true, // edit
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return MessageBubble(
          message: messages.reversed.toList()[index]['message'], // edit
          isCurrentUser: messages[index]['type'] == 'user',
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code when you tap on TextField

```
onTap: () {   
  _scrollController.animateTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, curve: Curves.easeOut, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
 }
```

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't scroll all the way till the end